# Json schema check all items enum are present in array of objects

Tags: json, validation, enums, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have json schema like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "country": {
        "type": "string",
        "maxLength": 2,
        "enum": ["aa", "bb"]
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "country"
    ]
  }
}
```

And json in this format:

```
[
  {"country": "aa"},
]
```

I want schema to check whether the json file contains all countries listed in enum:

```
[
  {"country": "aa"},
  {"country": "bb"},
]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with v5/6 contains keyword:

```
{
  "allOf": [
    { "contains": { "properties": { "country": { "constant": "aa" } } } },
    { "contains": { "properties": { "country": { "constant": "bb" } } } }
  ]
}
```

`"constant": "aa"` is another v5/6 keyword, same as `"enum": ["aa"]`.
At the moment [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) supports these keyword (a bit of self promotion).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying those things)

Answer (score 1):

For those who can't use @esp handy syntax, here's an old style solution:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "country": {
                "type": "string",
                "maxLength": 2,
                "enum": ["aa", "bb"]
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "country"
        ]
    },
    "allOf": [
        {"not": {"items": {"not": {"properties": {"country": {"enum": ["aa"]}}}}}},
        {"not": {"items": {"not": {"properties": {"country": {"enum": ["bb"]}}}}}}
    ]
}
```